# Joining many-to-many tables in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table layout as shown in this image.  One main table (**User**), and two many-to-many tables (**Preference** and **Location**) with junction tables.  I have set up the correct relationships in the data model to allow selections from these m-2-m tables....

[image]

The report tool I'm writing allows the user to select (from a checklist) any user preferences or user locations.  What I'd like to do is choose only the records from the **User** table where the **Preferences** OR **Locations** contains at least one of their selections.

Is this possible with a Linq query?  (I did previously do this in SQL, but it seemed easier to write in Linq until I got to this part!)

Many thanks,

EDIT: Visual Studio 2012, Entity Framework 4, SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Something like `Users.Where(x => Preferences.Any(y => y.UserID == x.UserID) || Locations.Any(y => y.UserID == x.UserID));`?

Answer (score 3):

```
from u in Users
where u.Locations.Any(l => l.Name == value) ||
      u.Preferences.Any(p => p.Title == value)
select u;
```

That will generate two EXISTS subqueries. Lambda syntax:

```
Users.Where(u => u.Locations.Any(l => l.Name == value) ||
                 u.Preferences.Any(p => p.Title == value));
```

Comment: Just as an after thought, if I have a dynamic list of values to compare - is there a better way of writing this than using l.Name == "xxx" || l.Name == "yyy" || l.Name == "zzz"  ?

Comment: @Simon you can create list of values `{ "xxx", "yyy", "zzz" }` and check if this list contains location or preference value: `u.Locations.Any(l => values.Contains(l.Name))`. I believe that should work with subquery.

Comment: Thank you. Just got there a second before your post.